# Elastic Beanstalk Application with RDS Free Tier

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I am new to AWS and am using Elastic Beanstalk to launch a PHP application in Free Tier. My question is whether AWS Elastic Beanstalk Application along with RDS still be considered as free-tier as a setup. 
For example, below is my current setup:
- I created a Elastic Beanstalk Application and deployed a PHP application
- Then I created an RDS using the option at the bottom of Beanstalk Configuration page (Data-Tier section). This created an RDS instance.

Now, per my understanding of Free Tier, ONE EC2 t2.micro instance is eligible for Free Tier. So, will this kind of setup be chargeable by Amazon?

Comment: If you are worried about going over the free-tier limits then I suggest reading the documentation: https://aws.amazon.com/free/ You will notice that you can have one db.t2.micro RDS instance, in addition to one t2.micro EC2 instance, along with lots of other services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate how much it will cost (and whether or not it qualifies for the free tier).

https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

Per the calculator:

- EC2 t2.micro is $8.50/month
- RDS t2.micro (5GB) is $13.03/month

However, the calculator also tells us that is free (with the free tier discount), which is consistent with their [general information page](https://aws.amazon.com/free/).

> **Amazon RDS**
>
> 750 Hours per month of db.t2.micro database usage
>   (applicable DB engines) Managed Relational Database Service for MySQL,
>   PostgreSQL, MariaDB, Oracle BYOL, or SQL Server
>
> **Amazon EC2**
>
> 750 Hours per month of Windows t2.micro instance usage

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Got it!

Answer (score 2):

RDS databases are separate from EC2 instances in terms of free tier (and pricing in general).

However I do not advise creating an RDS instance through beanstalk - while very convenient for development, it can cause an accidental database deletion in production.